# Website Scrolls very slow in Chrome, how to fix?

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome, scroll

Our website [eCigarettes Canada](http://www.ecigarettescanada.com/) scrolls very slow. It may scroll fast at the beginning, but soon after scrolling up and down is very slow. Does anyone know what may be causing this. From what i know we are not using background-size:cover anywhere in our css stylesheets.

Comment: Well its not a default feature or problem in chrome...you have used so many js files in your site...it is difficult to find out which file is it but definitely you slow scroll is applied due to some js file only...i should suggest try removing file 1 by 1 and check after removing which file you scroll is working

Comment: I understand this, but why is scrolling fast in Firefox and Internet Explorer and only slow in Chrome? This leads be to believe it is something else.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at the results gathered from running your website through Google's PageSpeed Insights: [Results](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ecigarettescanada.com%2F&tab=mobile).

It will take a little time to finish, but you'll see your desktop score is about 60/100. The main issues are the JavaScript, image optimization, lack of a proper caching scheme, and server response time. I would start fixing your site by minifying your JavaScript files and loading only one , instead of twenty-five. This alone should yield a better user experience. Here is a [free online tool](http://jscompress.com/) that allows you to upload multiple files right to the browser.

After that, I would optimize your images. There are multitudes of free optimization tools out there. Just pick one and see how far you get. These savings will definitely help page load.

If the site is still too slow, you need to investigate caching and server response delays. This lies beyond the scope of my answer and you'll have to see how the server your website is hosted on is configured.

Best of luck.

Comment: Hello i appreciate your detailed response to my issue. I will definately looking into page loading times with the website. I however am more focused on why the page scrolling is very slow. On Firefox the page scrolling is very quick, but in Chrome it is very slow scrolling up and down on the main page. I also checked Internet Explorer on Windows 10 and the scrolling up and down is very fast for me.

Comment: Andy, your answer seems to have absolutely nothing to do with OP's question (slow scrolling, not slow downloading).

Comment: Thanks for your cruel response!